# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

I am trying to connect to an external database but keep getting this error :

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I have tried everything on this post:

[Why is my php code not connecting to my remote MySql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879518/why-is-my-php-code-not-connecting-to-my-remote-mysql-database])

I can ping the server, I have a MYSQL service running on port 3306, I white listed my IP in cpanel in the remote MYSQL section, I granted all access in the mysql local server, I turned my firewall off, port 3306 is visible. I tried connecting through mysql bench and I get a 10060 error. I am using the cpanel credentials to connect, I tried creating a user for the database and using that in my code and it doesnt work either. I am using windows 7 64bit.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
// $servername = cpanel->server information->shared ip address
$servername = "example.com";

// username used to connect to cpanel
$username = "user";

// password used to connect to cpanel
$password = "pass";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=database_name", $username, 
$password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully"; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I dont know why would this be marked as a duplicate to that question, clearly I mention that I made the port 3306 visible and turned off my firewall.

Comment: try to connect to mysql using the command line client. If that succeeds, you know it's the PHP/Webserver configuration.