# Is there a way to find servername, username and password of an MySQL server if I can log in via phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine I can access a MariaDB Database via phpmyadmin, e.g.

```
https://test.com/phpMyAdmin

username: some_username
password: some_password
```

Now I just want to use php to search whether some value exists; However, to do so I need to connect to the database with a servername, username and password;

I tried the servername

```
https://test.com`
```

with username and password as above but no luck; Is there a way to find that out?

Right now my currect code looks like that:

```
<?php
$servername = "https://test.com";
$username = "some_username";
$password = "some_password";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "DB1");

// Überprüfe Verbindung
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

which gives me the error

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9
Connection failed: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Comment: What's the actual _code_ that you're using?

Comment: @PatrickQ Sorry, I updated it...

Comment: `$servername = "https://test.com`";` < there's a tick in there. Typo? (Edit: edited) Plus, it's probably not the server name you want, but `localhost`.  Hard to say.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately just a typo on stackoverflow not in my code... So there is no way to find the right information even if I am able to login in phpmyadmin? The database is definitely not on my local server/computer, if this helps..

Comment: Drop the `https://` part.  You also need to make sure that the database as a whole, and your user specifically, allows remote access.

Comment: Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 9
Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.        The error changed at least :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879518/why-is-my-php-code-not-connecting-to-my-remote-mysql-database

Comment: Okay, I can ping the server, but it is also not responding using MySQL Workbench - so according to the answers listed in the link, since I switched off my personal firewall, either there is no remote access or there is a firewall of the sql server blocking it, right? Either way, I have no chance to access it via php just with the login credentials that I have, right? So right now, all I can do is to export the database to a local database I assume?

Comment: Since we don't have any insights into the remote server, we don't know the exact reason why you're being blocked, and therefore can't really provide any more help at this time.  Your available options depend on how much access you have on that server.  Are you able to view/change firewall settings?  Are you able to view/edit global db connection settings?  Are you able to view/edit db user grants?  If the answer to all of those is "No", then there's really not much you can do.